# Single port KVM over IP

Tags: remote-access, keyboard-video-mouse

1. Does anyone know if "[Raritan Dominion KXII-101](http://www.kvm-switches-online.com/dkx2-101.html)" can be accessed with some standard protocol? (rdp, vnc, X, ...)
2. Are there any other single-port KVMs worth looking at? (a single port and a standard access protocol is what I'm after mainly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually those IP KVM machines load a java (or in the case of one particularly annoying Belkin, ActiveX) program that displays the remote screen and allows you to interact that way.

I've never seen one with VNC, and I'm fairly sure that RDP/X wouldn't work due to the limitations of only reading the video port.

Comment: We bought a cheap device that had a Java client.  Used wireshark and netcat to pick the protocol apart, managed to telnet to the device, discovered it was running custom debian on an ARM processor.  Modified the /etc/vnc files to persuade it not to ask for custom file formats, managed to connect with VNC for about 10s before it realised it wasn't the Java app, and termnated our session. Then it threw a segfault.  We sent it back to the supplier.

Comment: Nice hack! It's too bad that manufacturers try to prevent "fun" stuff

Answer (score 2):

It is accessed with a web browser over IP, as it says in its description.

Comment: Well - I learned not to trust the product descriptions and to confirm stuff like that ;)

Comment: Fair enough :) Most KVMs labeled as IP KVMs though are through a web browser, so that's one description that it's pretty safe to trust.